# Connecting to beans on GlassFish with Java SE Swing app

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, javabeans

So I want to create a JSF web app with beans but also I would like to create a Swing client app with that I could also connect to the JSF beans. 
But I dont rly know how to access those setter and other beans method with my Java SE Swing app. 
I know how to create a connection to my GlassFish server but I dont know how to go forward.

Comment: Swing and JSF are both UI technologies. One replaces the other. Maybe are you looking for webservices or something like that?

Comment: For example I would like to do something like this: Swing app with an adding ,,new client form", I click on the Swing button "Add", my Swing app sends the data to the bean on GlassFish, the bean does some logic stuff on the data and sends it to the MySQL database

Comment: webservices, then. But it looks like you have mixed the bussiness/persistence logic with your JSF, which is not a good thing (because now you cannot reuse it).